# Dont want to change selected value on reloading in Collection_tag in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I m using this code to display a drop down list. But when I select value and reload it, I want to display the selected values.

```
<%= collection_select("server", "id",@ndt,"ndname", "ndname",:prompt => "Select Server") %>
```

Like in textbox

```
<%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name]%>
```

On reloading,it displays the name in text box which we entered. Is there same thing for collection_tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:selected` option.

```
<%= collection_select("server", "id", @ndt,"ndname", "ndname", 
  {:prompt => "Select Server", :selected => "id_of_your_object"}) %>
```